# monaco editor navigate to symbol from outside editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using monaco editor v0.11.1.
Language: CSS
I want to navigate to the symbol (go to symbol) from outside editor via api.
I tried the below mentioned code.

```
this.editor.getAction('editor.action.quickOutline').run('body');
```

But it opens the list of symbols. But I want to navigate to the specific symbol like 'body', '.header'.
Thanks.